# "Pour your heart out" in Japanese

Tags: phrase-requests

How would you say "pour your heart out" in Japanese? Is there a phrase for this?

As in "I poured my heart and soul out to you".

Comment: Could you give an example how would you like to use this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an exact match, but these come close:

- ありのままの自分を見せる
  *show my true, bare self*
- 自分をさらけ出す
  *lay myself bare*
- 気持ちを包み隠さず話す
  *confess my true feelings*

I hesitate to use the word 心, especially if you plan on saying this to someone in real life. But if you don't mind sounding like a maudlin love song, you can replace the `自分` or `気持ち` in the above phrases with `心`.